# java program to count word in string

Tags: java

I am writing a java program to count the numbers of the occurence of each word in a string
Example :

```
" hello this is a java program this program count the words in string "

hello 1
this 2
is 1
a 1
java 1
program 2
```

I have finished coding but it didnt run and i dont know why. can you guys take a little time to examine it for me ?

```
import java.util.*;


/**
 *
 * @author user
 */
public class CountTheToken {

    static void stringCount ( String inputString)
    {
        HashMap<String,Integer> strCountMap
                = new HashMap<String,Integer>();




        StringTokenizer st1 = new StringTokenizer(inputString);



    String strArray[] = inputString.split(" ");



    for (String part : strArray )
    {
       strCountMap.put(part,0);
    }

        while (st1.hasMoreTokens())
           {
             for (String c : strArray)
             {
                 if ( strCountMap.containsKey(c))
                 {
                     strCountMap.put(c, strCountMap.get(c)+1);
                 }
                 else
                 {
                     strCountMap.put(c, 1);
                 }
             }
           }    


      for ( Map.Entry entry : strCountMap.entrySet())
       {
            System.out.println(entry.getKey()+" "+entry.getValue());
       }
    }
    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String str = "hello this is mario mario has moustache";
        stringCount (str);



        // TODO code application logic here
    }

}
```

Comment: Hey there, maybe you should elaborate the Problem, what is the output vs what you would expect.
Also the readability of your example is kinda bad, try formatting it, so the indentations are right.

Comment: thanks. do you know any good books , websites or documentaries which have the instruction about writing clean, easy-to-read code. Im very appreciated

Answer (score 1):

You need to eliminate your `for loop` within the `while loop`.  Do it like this.

```
while (st1.hasMoreTokens()) {
    String c = st1.nextToken();
    if (strCountMap.containsKey(c)) {
        strCountMap.put(c, strCountMap.get(c) + 1);
    } else {
        strCountMap.put(c, 1);
    }           
}
```

You did not need a `for loop`. Just rely on the `StringTokenizer` to do the job of iteration.

Comment: It worked. Thank you very much ^ ^